# Measure resistance

Tags: resistance-measurement

What's the simplest way to measure the resistance between two inputs and turn on the appropriate LED:

0Ω
≤
R ≤
1kΩ
... output = RED

10kΩ
≤
R ≤
100kΩ
.... output = YELLOW

1MΩ
≤
R ≤
∞
... output = GREEN

Zener diodes?

Comment: Hopefully this is a small, linear range. Resistors can vary over many many orders of magnitude.

Comment: In the real world every resistance is "some value". You never get exactly zero resistance and you never get infinite resistance. Put in some numbers.

Comment: Is this basically a resistor tester? The resistances being measured will not be connected to another circuit?

Comment: Kinda.
This is a FSR which, due to the z-axis pressure I am trying to measure, can only output 3 states. Sensor not touching (very high resistance), sensor touching (medium resistance), sensor crushing (zero).
So it is attached at the same circuit, I was thinking at a simple voltage divider with 2 Zeners for the thresholds and some mosfets to block the LEDs above that specific threshold, but I wonder if it can be simplified even further?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to establish some form of specification.

There should be 3 ranges (in ohms) in which you want some definite output. There must be gaps between the ranges where the output is not required to be one or the other.

So you should have something like:

0\$\Omega\$ \$\le\$ R \$\le\$ 1k\$\Omega\$  ... output = RED

10k\$\Omega\$ \$\le\$ R \$\le\$ 100k\$\Omega\$ .... output = YELLOW

1M\$\Omega\$ \$\le\$ R \$\le\$ \$\infty\$ ... output = GREEN

for intermediate values such as 2K the output can be either RED or YELLOW (or YELLOW or GREEN if the value is something like 330K).

I've used large differences, perhaps your differences are much smaller, but whatever the actual numbers are they need to be specified.

It might also help if you describe what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: That's how I should have posted the question.
Given 2 non overlapping ranges (values picked up here are fine), how would you approach detecting which range the resistance between two pins belong?
I edited the question to make it clear